# how to remove upload image validation in Django?

Tags: python, django, validation

How can I remove this validation in django? [image]

code in Django is like this:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="data", null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Do you define a `ModelForm`? Can you share the implementation of that `ModelForm`?

Comment: not really, this is the only code I have

Comment: Then exactly how do you render the form, and validate it? This looks like a validation issue, and usually a modelform does validation, or code in the view that handles that HTML form.

Comment: <h1>Add picture</h1>
            {{form.image}}
            <p id="status"></p>
 do you mean this one?

Comment: that will indeed render a form field, so that means the view behind this constructs a `ModelForm`...

Comment: image = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'file-upload-input', 'id': 'file-selector'}))
this is in my forms.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the field in a `ModelForm`, it will no longer be constructed by the corresponding model field, hence it will not take `blank=True` into account.

What you can do is only override the widget, so work with:

```
class SomeModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # no image = …

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ['image', 'and', 'other', 'fields']
        widgets = {
            'image': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'file-upload-input', 'id': 'file-selector'})
        }
```